# Pandas: extracting multiple rows from DataFrame with list of DatetimeIndices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a pandas Dataframe with the following index with seconds frequency:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2015-12-28 05:20:05', '2015-12-28 05:20:06',
               '2015-12-28 05:20:07', '2015-12-28 05:20:08',
               ...
               '2015-12-28 21:19:55', '2015-12-28 21:19:56',
               '2015-12-28 21:19:57', '2015-12-28 21:19:58']
```

I want to extract multiple rows at once, given a list of datetime strings. I tried:

```
df.loc[['2015-12-28 08:32:39', '2015-12-28 08:32:48']]
```

But I get the following error:

```
KeyError: "None of [['2015-12-28 08:32:39', '2015-12-28 08:32:48']] are in the [index]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert `list` to `datetime` by [`DatetimeIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) or [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
d = ['2015-12-28 05:20:05', '2015-12-28 21:19:58']
print (df.loc[pd.DatetimeIndex(d)])
```

Or:

```
print (df.loc[pd.to_datetime(d)])
```

Sample:

```
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2015-12-28 05:20:05', '2015-12-28 05:20:06',
               '2015-12-28 05:20:07', '2015-12-28 05:20:08',
               '2015-12-28 21:19:55', '2015-12-28 21:19:56',
               '2015-12-28 21:19:57', '2015-12-28 21:19:58'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'s': range(8)}, index=idx)  
print (df)
                     s
2015-12-28 05:20:05  0
2015-12-28 05:20:06  1
2015-12-28 05:20:07  2
2015-12-28 05:20:08  3
2015-12-28 21:19:55  4
2015-12-28 21:19:56  5
2015-12-28 21:19:57  6
2015-12-28 21:19:58  7

d = ['2015-12-28 05:20:05', '2015-12-28 21:19:58']
print (df.loc[pd.to_datetime(d)])
                     s
2015-12-28 05:20:05  0
2015-12-28 21:19:58  7

print (df.loc[pd.to_datetime(d)])
                     s
2015-12-28 05:20:05  0
2015-12-28 21:19:58  7
```