# pandas DataFrame selecting list of rows from DateTimeIndex - KeyError. Understanding why

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime, keyerror

I'm trying to understand why I get this error. I already have a solution for this issue and it was actually solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45213834/pandas-extracting-multiple-rows-from-dataframe-with-list-of-datetimeindices), just need to understand why it doesn't work as I was expecting.

I would like to understand why this throws a KeyError:

```
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=4)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.identity(4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))
df.loc[['20130102', '20130103'],:]
```

with the following feedback:

```
KeyError: "None of [['20130102', '20130103']] are in the [index]"
```

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45213834/pandas-extracting-multiple-rows-from-dataframe-with-list-of-datetimeindices), the solution is just to do:

```
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(['20130102','20130104']),:]
```

So the problem is definitely with the way loc takes the string list as argument for selecting from a DateTimeIndex. However, I can see that the following calls are ok for this function:

```
df.loc['20130102':'20130104',:]
```

and

```
df.loc['20130102']
```

I would like to understand how this works and would appreciate any resources I can use to predict the behavior of this function depending of how it is being called. I read [Indexing and Selecting Data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) and [Time Series/Date functionality](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#datetimeindex-partial-string-indexing) from pandas documentation but couldn't find an explanation for this.

Comment: If anyone has a similar issue, what solved it for me is removing the duplicate indices:

`
df = df.loc[~df.index.duplicated(keep='first')];
sliced_df = df[start_time:end_time]
`

Comment: As well as sort the index: df = df.sort_index()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, when you pass an array like object to `loc`, Pandas is going to try to locate each element of that array in the index.  If it doesn't find it, you'll get a `KeyError`.  And! you passed an array of strings when the values in the index are `Timestamp`s... so those strings definitely aren't in the index.

However, Pandas also tries to make things easier for you.  In particular, with a `DatetimeIndex`, If you were to pass a string scalar

```
df.loc['20130102']

A    0.0
B    1.0
C    0.0
D    0.0
Name: 2013-01-02 00:00:00, dtype: float64
```

Pandas will attempt to parse that scalar as a `Timestamp` and see if that value is in the index.

If you were to pass a `slice` object

```
df.loc['20130102':'20130104']

              A    B    C    D
2013-01-02  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
2013-01-03  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
2013-01-04  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

Pandas will also attempt to parse the bits of the slice object as `Timestamp` and return an appropriately sliced dataframe.

Your `KeyError` is simply passed the limits of how much helpfulness the Pandas Devs had time to code.